# How to delimit data in one column into new columns

Tags: sql-server, substring, delimiter, charindex

I'm stuck at how to delimit my data into new column.

Example:

```
Column_A
q201,r331,q402,r0[213453]
```

I need to get the value inside bracket, 213453

From what I get after searching the information, I need to use

```
substring and charindex
```

but this case this case is like 2 times delimiter. Any idea how to do this?

Thanks

Comment: You have to search both of the delimiters with charindex and then use substring

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(Column_A,
                 CHARINDEX('[', Column_A) + 1,
                 CHARINDEX(']', Column_A) - CHARINDEX('[', Column_A) - 1)
FROM yourTable
```

This answer assumes that you only have one bracketed quantity, or if more than one, then you would accept taking the first one.  If your actual data differs, then update your question.

Comment: Hi Tim, i got error message 'Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value 'my_value' to data type int. My actual data format is same as my question.

Comment: My query should work AFAIK.  Perhaps you copied it/interpreted it wrongly and hence the error.  Maybe update your question with what you are really trying to do.

Comment: Hi Tim, when I look to my data some of datas are nvarchar type like [213412easdaqwr], is that affect this case?

Comment: I am not sure why my query would not work for you.  Try testing each piece separately and find out what is wrong.